# Fire print handler of embed html element

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed

I got a pdf as a base64 string which is used as source of embed html element.

```
<embed id="pdf-embed" src="data:application/pdf;base64,B64STR"></embed>
```

It is opened by browsers by their pdf view plugin, but how can I start print this pdf document in javascript?

e.g.:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#pdf-embed').print();
});
```

This code does not work, because seems like embed does not have its print function.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody will face the same issue as me:

I used dompdf to generate pdf and to fire print handler you have to add print() in html string in pdf.

So your html would be as in this example:

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">print();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you!